# how can I mocking property of type by Moq assembly?

Tags: c#, moq

I'm trying to mock a class, called EnvironmentManager, which contains a property called WebService_UserName than this property uses in a function called CallMeAsync.
How can I mock this private property for write a unit test?

Comment: Why you are trying to mock a private property of a class? Ideally it should not that's why it is declared as private.

Answer (score 0):

Generally if you pass in dependencies into your constructor, it's easier to test the object. Create a constructor to pass in value of your private variable.

```
public EnvironmentManager()  //what you currently have?
{
    _webService_UserName = new WebService_UserName();
}

public EnvironmentManager(object webService_UserName)  //passing dependency in instead
{
    _webService_UserName = webService_UserName;
}
```

I suspect in this example WebService_UserName is actually a string so mocking isn't required at all.

```
var underTest = new EnvironmentManager("WebService_UserName example");
var actual = underTest.CallMeAsync().Result;
Assert.Equal("expected result", actual)
```

If I'm wrong and you actually need to mock a dependency

```
var mockedDependency = new Mock<WebService_UserName>(); 
/*set up for mockedDependency */
var underTest = new EnvironmentManager(mockedDependency.Object);
var actual = underTest.CallMeAsync().Result;
Assert.Equal("expected result", actual)
```

*msg to deletion queue, I'm just trying to help the user, not save the question*